# Magento 2.3 Export not working | temando.CRITICAL: "accountId" is required

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, export, temando

I am unable to "Export" any products on my Magento ver 2.3.3 site.

The error in the log file:

```
[2020-01-10 15:12:40] temando.CRITICAL: "accountId" is required. Enter and try again. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\InputException(code: 0): \"accountId\" is required. Enter and try again. at /domains/staging.domain.co.uk/http/vendor/magento/framework/Exception/InputException.php:91)"} []
```

---

I tried to disable the module but I am getting the following error when trying to export:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Temando\Shipping\Model\ResourceModel\Repository\PackagingRepositoryInterface
```

I have removed the caches and content of the "generated" directory. Still the same error.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I managed to disable the module.

After disabling the module, I was still getting an error of:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Temando\Shipping\Model\ResourceModel\Repository\PackagingRepositoryInterface
```

It happened to be a reference to a temando source model in the eav_attribute table. In table **eav_attribute** search for "`temando`" in the **source_model** column and remove all entries.

I hope someone will find this useful.

Comment: for me it worked just removing the attributes from all the attribute sets, as I was worried about deleting attributes that were in fact "preinstalled". 
Until some reporting tool I installed decided it needs all attributes triggered, even though not in anything. Might have to delete.